# How do I embed a web browser into my Cocoa application?

Tags: cocoa, macos, web

I need to learn how to add a web browser into a cocoa application. (Mac)

Answer (score 6):

Try [WebKit](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/DisplayWebContent.html).  In particular, you might find the `MiniBrowser` example that comes with the developer tools interesting.  It should be at `/Developer/Examples/WebKit/MiniBrowser`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very difficult:
1) add a WebView object to your interface builder project.

2) (this is the important part) be sure to implement the required delegate methods and set your implementing class as the WebView delegate (in IB).  I don't recall exactly, but I think there are like 6 methods you need to implement in your delegate... then it will just work.
(of course, check the example code...)

Comment: Is this still the case? I cannot find the delegate.